# Can't write tmp files in Heroku/Sinatra

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

Trying to write a temporary file on Heroku (Cedar), which seems like it should be possible, according to the documentation.  Yet this code snippet fails:

```
get '/test' do
   myfile = File.new("./tmp/testemp.txt", "w+")
   myfile.puts("Abracadabra")
   myfile.close
   "End of test"
end
```

Any suggestions what I might be doing wrong? The "End of test" output shows up on the served web page, so this path is definitely getting followed.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by “fails”? You open a file, write to it but then don’t use it – what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is writing to the file `/tmp/testemp.txt`, but you are then returning `"End of test"` at the end of your method, which is why that is returned to the web browser.

That last thing you return will get rendered to the web browser by default.